# how to upload both image and docx file to server in single api call in swift4

Tags: ios, swift

i need to upload one image and one pdf file to server in single api call along with some parameter`.i do not know how to create a body for this. i know to create a body for single data but do not know to create a body for two data. can you please tell me the createBodyWithParameter and how to assign the filename and Mimetype for both datas.

```
func createBodyWithParameters(parameters: [String: Any]?, ImagePathKey: String?, imageDataKey: NSData,FilePathKey: String?, fileDatakey: NSData, boundary: String) -> NSData {

    let body = NSMutableData();

    if parameters != nil {
        for (key, value) in parameters! {
            body.appendString(string:"--\(boundary)\r\n")
            body.appendString(string: "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(key)\"\r\n\r\n")
            body.appendString(string: "\(value)\r\n")
        }
    }



    let filename = ".png"
    let mimetype = "image/jpg"

    let filenames = ".pdf"
    let mimetypes = "application/pdf"

    body.appendString(string: "--\(boundary)\r\n")
    body.appendString(string: "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(ImagePathKey!)\"; filename=\"\(filename)\"\r\n")
    body.appendString(string: "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(FilePathKey!)\"; filename=\"\(filenames)\"\r\n")
    body.appendString(string: "Content-Type: \(mimetype)\r\n\r\n")
    body.appendString(string: "Content-Type: \(mimetypes)\r\n\r\n")
    body.append(imageDataKey as Data)
    body.append(fileDatakey as Data)
    body.appendString(string: "\r\n")

    body.appendString(string: "--\(boundary)--\r\n")

    return body
}`

let parameter = ["UserId":1,"Name":userNameOrEamilTF.text!,"PhoneCode":countryCodeTF.text!,"Phone":phone,"DisplayPreference":displayReference,"region":region] as [String : Any]
```

this is what i created body and assigning data and key here and imagedata, filedata has data

```
request.httpBody = createBodyWithParameters(parameters: param, filePathKey: "profile", imageDataKey: imageData! as NSData,FilePathKey: "Resume", fileDatakey: filedata as NSData, boundary: boundary) as Data
```

Comment: Boundary separator and metadata should precede each element you add and define end of the body. For more details please refer to wili page multipart format: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#Multipart_messages

Comment: how to add this Content Type: application/octet-stream into my content type sir . i tried but i am not aware with this . can you help me once please